# Hello, I have a computational q. regarding combination/permutations

Tags: permutation, combinations

A brief intro. I am creating a medical software. I forget some of the computation/permutation theorems in college. Let's say I have five nerves. Median, ulnar, radial, tibial, peroneal. I can choose one, two, three, four, or all five of them in any combintation. What is the equation to find the maxmimum number of combinations I can make?

For example;
median
median + ulnar
median + ulnar + radial
etc etc

ulnar + median = median + ulnar. so those would be repetitive. Thank you for your help. I know this isn't directly programming related, but I thought you guys would be familiar.

Comment: I think it is `2^n`. You may want to `-1` if you want to exclude the case of 0 choice.

Answer (score 0):

The comment that says it is (2^n)-1 is correct. 2^n is the number of possible subsets you can form from a set of n objects (in this case you have 5 objects), and then in your case, you don't want to count the empty set, so you subtract out 1.

I'm sure you can do the math, but for the sake of completeness, for 5 nerves, there would be 2^5 - 1 = 32 - 1 = 31 possible combinations you could end up with.